# Can chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText load string from a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am aware that using the following will load in the text with a background over my Google Chrome extension and that it will truncate it to the first four letters.

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "loading" } );
```

But what I am want to do is allowing the part were it says `loading` to display the string result from a js script. I have check around the web and on StackOverflow for answers but I am yet to find anything relevant to what I am trying to do so I decided to ask the question here.

My manifest.json has the background,js loaded:

```
"background": {
  "scripts":["background.js"]
}
```

**background.js** -Then inside the `background.js` I have been trying to get it to work by loading the results from `number.js` but I am just not been able to make it work what so ever. I know the code is wrong here becuase I have messed it up but I will include it so you can get an understanding of what I am trying to do:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'number.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);

chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "loading" } );

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
{code:"globalVarName = {'scriptOptions': {...}};" },
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "number.js"},
```

**number.js** - And then what I am finally trying to load is the string from `number.js`:

```
var ip = "chromahills.net";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://minecraft-api.com/v1/get/?server=" + ip, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (data.status) {
                        document.write(data.players.online);
                } else {
                        document.write("Fail");
                }
        }
}

xhr.send();
```

**Question**

So, to get straight to the point my questions are as follows:

- Is it possible to include a javascript string in the `.setBadgeText`?
- And if so what would be the most effective way of doing this?

I know this is quite a long block of text but I tried to include as much detail as possible so you can understand what I am trying to do and hopefully explain a better way to do what I am doing or even if it is actually possible.

## Edit

I have removed my progress to avoid confusion now the issue is fixed. If you wish to view what I tried then click here -> http://jsfiddle.net/lukexf/5d72Q/ or read below for the solution

Comment: `document.write` is definitely wrong inside background.js ... but if your last code segment works, then the code segment of my answer below will work too. Of course you have to make sure that my code segment is wrapped in a function and that you call this function at the *right time*

Comment: when you say `it fails to work` ... what do you get in your debug console?

Comment: @devnull69 http://puu.sh/93fTu.png this is my code. I have tested this elsewhere in JS (with not using chrome parts) and it works fine. `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: data.players.online } );` simple does not show up on the icon. Where as `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "test" } );` would obviously return test and a background. 

Even if the text fails to load then the background also does. There are no errors in the debug console either.

Comment: please add `console.log(data.players.online)` to the `if` part of the code and tell us exactly what the output is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lukexf/B78B9/ I tried putting it in, but I'm not exactly sure where it should go as it is not logging anything. So I have put part of the project on jsfiddle. If you could just point out where it would go it would really help me. Thanks so much for your help so far :)

Comment: I amended the fiddle accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/B78B9/1/ and tried to execute the code removing the `chrome` specific parts here http://jsfiddle.net/B78B9/2/ ... it worked flawlessly. I would suggest you post your relevant code from your background script completely (including the function wrapper and the calling part)

Comment: You should probably edit your question (and now - answer) to trim out irrelevant code. Only `checkState` is relevant

Comment: @Xan I removed the edits of the post. Which should avoid confusion. Thanks everyone for your help. You can see the end result here http://puu.sh/93v6d.png So much effort for such small result. But I'm glad it was fixed.

Comment: Do not post the solution in the question. Post it as an answer. You can answer your own question and even accept your answer so that people know what worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally Fixed the issue. This was done via  allowing the function to check the state of the IP and then display it under the correct conditions. Not using any of the xhr has helped because it now loads a much more efficient way. I have also learnt how to include images based on the status of the string.

I hope this helps other people as much as it did me.

```
var ip;
var timer;

function loadExtension () {
    if (!ip) {
        ip = 'chromahills.net';
    }

    checkState();
}

function checkState () {
    $.get('https://aron.li/mss/ping.php?ip=' + ip, function(data) {
        if (data.max != null) {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [122, 186, 122, 255] });
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'up.png'});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '' + data.online});
        } else {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'down.png'});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'OFF' });
            hrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
        }
    });

    timer = setTimeout(checkState, 1000*60);
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (true) {
        case request.restart:
        timer = null;
        loadExtension();
        break;
    }
    return true;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadExtension();
});
```

Comment: Aha, so the problem was with `setBadgeText` not expecting a number. Then yes, `''+n` will fix it.

Comment: Yer, I did think it had to include the an empty string with concatenation to the data.online, I just didn't test it right. Finally it is fixed though, phew!

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can show a Javascript string in `.setBadgeText`, in fact it is the only thing you can show there :-)

So, I tried to understand the knack of your question ... and I think you want to somehow *call* number.js and then retrieve the output (the part that `document.write` writes to the screen).

But this would be the wrong approach.

Why not implement the following code directly in background.js (where you can easily access the badgeText)?

```
var ip = "chromahills.net";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://minecraft-api.com/v1/get/?server=" + ip, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (data.status) {
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: data.players.online.toString() } );
            } else {
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "Fail" });
            }
    }
}

xhr.send();
```

Comment: I made edit's above my post so you can see what I have tested. I included the API below where I get the data from. You can scroll down to see how the API works for what I am using before. [**Link Here**](http://minecraft-api.com/getting-started) This includes the JavaScript useage at the bottom.

Comment: @devnull69 So the problem basically boiled down to `setBadgeText` not accepting a number for `text` attribute. Can you edit your answer so it is correct? (e.g. `'' + data.players.online`)

Comment: I added a `toString` because it's more self-explaining than `''+number`